# How do I use the latest support library (Getting failed to resolve error with support library 26.0.2 and compileSDKVersion 26)?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated my compileSdkVersion to 26. This is how my gradle file looks now.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ##############
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Predictably, I get warnings for the mismatch(?) in the versions of support library (25.3.1) and the CompileSdkVersion (26).

I have tried to update the support library version to the below versions:

- compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
- compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'

**The Problem**

None of them worked. Both cases show `Failed to resolve` errors. Clicking on `Install Repository and sync project` freezes Android Studio for a couple of seconds and nothing else happens.

Am I missing something?

The latest Android support version library [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#design) is `26.0.2`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should add this in your  **`App Level`** <kbd>build.gradle</kbd> section.

**Finally**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild`** and **`Run`** .

**FYI**

If you're using a version of **`Gradle higher than 4.1`**, you must use :

```
allprojects {
      repositories {  
        google()

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to File->Settings->Android SDK->SDK Tools.
Then in Support Repository dropdown, check the android support repository checkbox and update it.

Comment: Support library is not delivered via downloadable maven repository anymore. Version 26 is only available in the google repo.

Comment: I am not using maven @EugenPechanec.

Comment: Me neither, Maven repository != Maven.