# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:palette-v7:26.0.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-build, android-palette

I am having this error on Android Studio:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:palette-v7:26.0.1
Install Repository and sync project
Open File
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

When I click 'Install Repository and sync project' nothing happens.

I already checked and tried similar questions's answers. But still problem exists.

Here is my project level build.gradle code:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my app level build.gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$rootDir/utils.gradle"
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

//repositories {
//    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
//}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    def applicationName = "xyz"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xyz"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 16
        versionName "1.7"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "xyz",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        buildConfigField 'String', 'END_POINT', toJavaCodeString(END_POINT)
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storePassword 'android'
            storeFile file('../keystore/debug.jks')
        }
        release {
            keyAlias 'xyz'
            keyPassword 'xyz'
            storePassword 'xyz'
            storeFile file('../../../Keystore/xyz.keystore')
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode
            versionName defaultConfig.versionName
            applicationId "xyz"
        }

        prod {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode
            versionName defaultConfig.versionName
            applicationId "xyz"
        }

    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig getSigningConfig()
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    def date = new Date();
                    def formattedDate = date.format('dd-MM - HH:mm:ss')
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent,
                            output.outputFile.name.replace("app-prod-release", applicationName + " v" + defaultConfig.versionName + " - " + formattedDate)
                    )
                }
            }

        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), "rules-proguard-debug.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

}

ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = "26.0.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:customtabs:${supportLibraryVersion}"
//    compile "com.android.support:support-dynamic-animation:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile 'com.tsengvn:typekit:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.0'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.8.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.7.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:community-material-typeface:1.7.22.1@aar'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.2.1'
    compile('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary:adjustable-imageview:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.florent37:viewanimator:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.7'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.4.7'

//    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.2, 3.99.99]'

    def gmsVersion = '11.2.+'
    compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${gmsVersion}") {
        force = true
    }
    compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${gmsVersion}") {
        force = true
    }
    compile("com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibraryVersion}") {
        force = true
    }
    compile("com.android.support:support-v13:${supportLibraryVersion}") {
        force = true
    }
    compile("com.android.support:customtabs:${supportLibraryVersion}") {
        force = true
    }

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:' + gmsVersion

    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+'

//    compile 'org.solovyev.android:checkout:1.0.0'

//    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
//    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
//    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'

}
```

Project and app level build.gradle code added.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46047978/3395198

Comment: Already tried and then posted this question. Those ones are not working for me. @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: Reopen this question. Show your project level `build.gradle`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the best way to do it.

In your root level gradle.build use below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file change the wrapper version as below

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip
```

also in your app level build.gradle make sure you are using 26 vesion as below

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```