# Build fails when generating APK but not building and deploying

Tags: android, apk, build.gradle, android-proguard

My project builds and runs on my emulator, but fails when I try to generate an APK for my project.  I am receiving the following the error when I attempt to generate the release APK:

> Warning:com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmTaskService: can't find
>   referenced field 'android.os.IBinder zzaHj' in program class
>   com.google.android.gms.gcm.PendingCallback
>
> Warning:there were 1
>   unresolved references to program class members.
>
> Warning:Exception
>   while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above
>   warnings first.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

---

**My proguard-rules.pro**

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}

# Attempted below to fix issue
#-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
#-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
  google()
  // Alternative attempt to resolve
  //    jcenter()
  //    maven {
  //        url "https://maven.google.com"
  //    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1"
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

List<String> dirs = [
        'main',     // main sample code; look here for the interesting stuff.
        'common',   // components that are reused by multiple samples
        'template'] // boilerplate code that is generated by the sample template process

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.11"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            dirs.each { dir ->
                java.srcDirs "src/${dir}/java"
                res.srcDirs "src/${dir}/res"
            }
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
        androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']

    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true // Enables code shrinking for the release build type.
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

**Attempts to fix**

1. I have tried adding the following to my `proguard-rules.pro` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24109609/4206520)):

   -keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
   -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

But this just creates the following issue:

> Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't
>   write
>   [/Users/myName/Documents/myProjectFolder/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/release/jars/3/1f/main.jar]
>   (Can't read
>   [/Users/myName/.android/build-cache/a80bb41778b1f73h09e3t326jn804m46e280aw10/output/jars/classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)]
>   (Duplicate zip entry
>   [classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/gcm/PendingCallback.class]))

2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46047978/4206520
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33953133/4206520

---

**Does anyone understand why my build fails when generating APK but not building and deploying (and how to prevent it from happening)?**

Comment: You have `"com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1"` and
    `"com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1"`, maybe this could produce problem. I think adding latest support version is the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
```

from `dependencies` in `build.gradle` file

Use individual modules in dependencies as given in below link
[Set up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Duplicate Entry error means, two same classes are there in your project and there exists conflicts b/w them

Comment: Thanks for the response Sangeet.  I believe this may be on the right track, but only doing this (for ex. removing `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'` and adding `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.2'`) causes the error `Error:(37, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.2` and then nothing happens when I click the prompt to "Install Repository and sync project"

Comment: You could install google play services from Android SDK manager itself