# Support Library is not Compatible

Tags: java, android

In android studio, i want to update my SDK version. I have updated to maximum and current max version is 25. But  my supported libraries are of version 26.

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
 compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

I am getting error in these lines. Please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: the current max is API 27, please go to documentation on support lib to get proper version. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: Build tools should be the same level, in case of buildToolsVersion '27.0.1' support lib version should be 27+ : e.g. "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2"

Comment: maybe you have this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047943/how-do-i-use-the-latest-support-library-getting-failed-to-resolve-error-with-su?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If your library version is 26, then try this:

```
    implementation('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'animated-vector-drawable'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation('com.android.support:design:26.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'animated-vector-drawable'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    } 
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```